# Strict inequality of vector norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, vectors, normed-spaces

Given a non orthogonal projection $p$ and non zero vector $x$. I am going to prove that
$$\|Px\|<c\|x\|$$
for some $c<1$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the usual Euclidean norm. I can only have the following:
$$\|Px\|\le \|P\|\|x\|\le \|x\|$$
which is weaker than what I wanted. Any advice?

Comment: Just a comment on the "weaker statement": If $P$ is a non-orthogonal projection, $\|P\|>1$.

Comment: Do you mean $||P||<1||?$

Comment: A submultiplicative norm of any nonzero projector is bounded from below by one because it is idempotent.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: I understand. So, how would I bound $\|Px\|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "shear-projection" in 2-d which is not orthogonal, e.g. has matrix representation $A = (0,0;\alpha,1)$ for some $\alpha \neq 0$, then with the vector $v = (0,1)^T$, you have $Av = v$ so your inequality can't hold. Are you leaving out some conditions to prohibit this case?